# The latest upgrade disables php7 for apache2

Tags: apache2, php7

Please let me know what logs you need to be able to solve this..

```
root@BudanParakeet:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# uname -v
#19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 11 18:33:49 UTC 2017
root@BudanParakeet:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled#

root@BudanParakeet:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# vi php7.0.conf 
root@BudanParakeet:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# service apache2 restart
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status apache2.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
root@BudanParakeet:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# journalctl -xe
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
nov 05 18:35:57 BudanParakeet systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
nov 05 18:35:57 BudanParakeet apachectl[4502]: apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.c
nov 05 18:35:57 BudanParakeet apachectl[4502]: Action 'start' failed.
nov 05 18:35:57 BudanParakeet apachectl[4502]: The Apache error log may have more information.
nov 05 18:35:57 BudanParakeet systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
nov 05 18:35:57 BudanParakeet systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
nov 05 18:35:57 BudanParakeet systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
nov 05 18:35:57 BudanParakeet systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: So what is the syntax of "Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.c" ?

Comment: it points to LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so called from root@BudanParakeet:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# vi /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load

Comment: I suppose the full file name wit the error on line 146 is /etc/apache2/apache2.conf. But it is unclear what means The latest upgrade. Is it a upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10? I couldn't found the exact answer that I saw these days, but there was desried similar issue. The problem was that 17.10 comes with PHP 7.1, but Apache's php module wasn't updated. So the solution was `sudo a2dismod php7.0`; `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.1`; `sudo a2enmod php7.1`; `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`.

Comment: @pa4080 don't you want to put that as an answer?

Comment: It should be duplicate of [PHP not working after upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967678/php-not-working-after-upgraded-to-ubuntu-17-10). But I found it too late.

Answer (score 3):

The problem could be that, Ubuntu 17.10 comes with PHP 7.1, but the Apache's php module wasn't updated. So [the solution could be](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967678/php-not-working-after-upgraded-to-ubuntu-17-10) to disable and remove the old module and install and enable the new one:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo apt remove libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.1
sudo a2enmod php7.1
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```