# Upgrade to 17.10 breaks phpmyadmin configuration

Tags: apache2, 17.10, phpmyadmin

I was asked to rephrase this posting as it was mistakenly confused with another question. So here is the rewrite:

I upgraded my server to 17.10. I had to run a2enmod to fix the php7.1 problem as mentioned elsewhere, and then everything worked fine - which I knew because the website was written in PHP and it worked as before. The only thing that was broken was phpmyadmin. When I ran it, all I got is a bunch of text. I tried purging it from the system and then reinstalling it, but no no avail.

Comment: How do you determinate that PHP works fine? Through CLI or thorough WEB?

Comment: And [PHP not working after upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967678/php-not-working-after-upgraded-to-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: Sorry that I was not clear on the status of PHP. This is a production server running a web site made in PHP. The web site works fine, as does running phpinfo(). I have not tested it with the CLI.

Comment: Latest news: I set up a new test LAMP server, installed phpmyadmin via apt-get and it worked. Therefore I have narrowed the problem down to a misconfiguration somewhere. So my new question is now: can anyone suggest where or what the config problem might be? Which files should I be looking at? The server in question is a simple LAMP server with no other modules installed. It has worked flawlessly for the past five years through all of the upgrades.

Comment: Hello, @phs, please read this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/969440/566421 ... additionally you could [edit] your question with this new information and we can vote to reopen it.

Comment: Hi again. I found the simple solution elsewhere. All I had to do was delete my browser cache. Afterwards phpmyadmin worked fine. Hope this helps others...

Comment: Don't refer to the comments in your question but enter all necessary information in the question itself.  Therefore [edit] the question, remove any irrelevant info and add in the relevant one.  In this case, you can also answer your own question to get more rep. **:-)**

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the cached files in your web browser will fix the problem.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit - deleting the cache will not fix every problem. Yo could start with "I fixed it by...."  and maybe continue with "I found the solution ....".